# onAfterModuleList not triggered in Home or in Wrapper menu type?

Tags: plugin, plugin-events

I got a plugin that uses the onAfterModuleList event, it works fine on most menu types. But it doesn't seem to be triggered in neither home or wrapper menu types. Event though there are modules assigned to those menu types. 
Is this correct? or should it be triggered whenever there is a module assigned to the page

I am currently testing in Joomla 3.7.3

** Edit **
com_search views also don't seem to trigger that.
Any ideas how I could trigger onAfterModuleList trough the plugin for components that do not trigger that?

Answer (score 1):

With this code all the modules are listed at each menuitem incl. home

```
public function onAfterModuleList(&$modules)
{
    foreach ($modules as $module)
    {
        echo '<pre>'; echo $module->title; echo '</pre>';
    }
    return true;
}
```

I placed this method in a custom system plugin.